# Sort a different list based on another?

Tags: python, list, sorting

So I have some lists:

```
shape1 = [[0, 0], [0, 100], [100, 100], [100, 0]]
shape2 = [[300, 300], [300, 450], [450, 450], [450, 300]]
list1 = [shape1, shape2]
height_y = [100, 150]
```

So I want to sort the shapes based on their heights (largest to smallest). It's really easy to sort the height_y list, however the heights are based on the shapes which are correlated to the same positions. So if I sort height_y, how can I sort list1 so that the shapes move into the same position as the height_y list after being sorted? I do not however want the arrangement of the points in the shape lists to change.

End Goal:

```
height_y = [150, 100]
list1 = [shape2, shape1]
```

Note: I'm only using two shapes here (defined by points) but I want this to be able to work with any number of shapes (upwards of a hundred).

Comment: An overall better solution might be to collect all the information about a shape in one place, such as a dict or a custom class, and then you'd only need one list of these objects, which is easily sorted.

Comment: The only issue with that is most of my data needs to stay in lists because it needs to be edited/changed on the fly (All of the shapes get moved/rotated over and over again to satisfy spacing/gravity/ordering conditions).

Comment: I don't see how that is a problem; dicts and custom classes are edited just as easily as list entries.  But I'll take your word for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `zip` em and sort.

```
In [489]: list1, height_y = map(list, (zip(*sorted(zip(list1, height_y), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))))

In [490]: list1
Out[490]: [shape2, shape1] # shortened for aesthetic purposes (it's a list of lists)

In [491]: height_y
Out[491]: [150, 100]
```

Breakdown:

1. `zip(list1, height_y)`: zip them together
2. `sorted(---(1)---, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`: sort the tuples in reverse based on the first value in each tuple (the height)
3. `zip(*---(2)----)`: unzip the tuples, you get a list of two tuples
4. `map(list, ---(3)---)`: convert list of tuple to list of lists

Comment: You don't need `map(list, ...)` unpacking will do that for you.

Comment: @AChampion I know... Problem being they're unpacked as tuples, not lists.

Comment: That is indeed more accurate to the OP's expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only shape and height. I suggest to use dictionary and then sort it by value like:

```
 import operator

 dict = {}
 sorted_dict = sorted(dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```